# MT5202: Native linking failed - Xamarin.iOS 7 - ExternalAccessory

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to use a native objective-C Framework by creating a Xamarin.iOS binding project. The binding project itself compiles fine but, the iOS app project that references it, dont build whenever I add some line of code that uses this binding library. The erro is:

```
Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)
```

I had seek over the internet, including here, and see lots of people with similar problem but it was related to the architecture that the library was compiled. So to be sure, I've checked the library in the command tools and the result was that I should have it working in both Simulator and real Device. The commands and outputs was:

```
# xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libDTEFMobile.a
Architectures in the fat file: libDTEFMobile.a are: armv7 armv7s i386
```

and

```
# file libDTEFMobile.a
libDTEFMobile.a: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
libDTEFMobile.a (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
libDTEFMobile.a (for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)):    current ar archive random library
libDTEFMobile.a (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
```

So just to be sure, I've checked my linkwith.cs file in the binding project and this is what I have:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libDTEFMobile.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true)]
```

The last logs on my Build Output are:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -c -o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o -x assembler /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.s
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -Wl,-pie  -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk  /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/M2MobileiOS.exe.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/M2.Mobile.Bindings.iOS.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libDTEFMobile.a -o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/M2MobileiOS.app/M2MobileiOS -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_log /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -Wl,-pie  -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk  /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/M2MobileiOS.exe.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/M2.Mobile.Bindings.iOS.dll.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libDTEFMobile.a -o /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/M2MobileiOS.app/M2MobileiOS -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_log /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[PaxMessager connectByBT] in libDTEFMobile.a(DTEFMobile)
  "_EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[PaxMessager connectByBT] in libDTEFMobile.a(DTEFMobile)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libDTEFMobile.a(DTEFMobile)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libDTEFMobile.a(DTEFMobile)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_EASessionController)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
  at MonoTouch.Application.NativeLink () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Application.BuildApp () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Application.Build () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

---------------------- Done ----------------------
```

And, my Xamarin.iOS version details are:

```
Xamarin Studio
Version 4.0.12 (build 3)
Installation UUID: 7348d641-ed6d-4c8a-b59a-116674e06dfd
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.3 ((no/8d3b4b7)
    GTK 2.24.20
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302030000

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 5.0 (3332.25)
Build 5A1413

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 7.0.0.11 (Trial Edition)
Hash: aa35ba3
Branch: 
Build date: 2013-18-09 16:42:48-0400

Build Information
Release ID: 400120003
Git revision: 593d7acb1cb78ceeeb482d5133cf1fe514467e39
Build date: 2013-08-07 20:30:53+0000
Xamarin addins: 25a0858b281923e666b09259ad4746b774e0a873

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.8.5
Darwin Gutembergs-MacBook-Pro.local 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0
    Mon Jul 29 16:33:49 PDT 2013
    root:xnu-2050.48.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Anybody has a clue on how did I get this working? The library I'm trying to use is linked to ExternalAccessory.framework so I can access a bluetooth device and this is what the logs seems to complain about...

Thanks for the help, really appreciate...

Gutemberg

Answer (score 3):

You must link with the ExternalAccessory framework, Xamarin.iOS can't determine automatically that this needs to be done for your bindings.

This is easy to do, just add the Frameworks property to the LinkWith attribute in your binding project:

```
[LinkWith (..., Frameworks = "ExternalAccessory")]
```

Comment: Thanks Rolf, now I get the following error:
duplicate symbol _Sleep in: /Users/gutemberg/Projects/M2.Mobile/M2.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libDTEFMobile.a(DTEFMobile)
    /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a(wthreads.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This one is a bit harder and will probably require updates to either libDTEFMobile or Xamarin.iOS. Can you file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and attach your project?

Comment: Rolf, just created the bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14896 I created it private due to company privacy but as soon as we get a solution I'll post here how we fixed it. Thanks for the support

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro did you ever get this fixed?